# Is it possible to browse CV's as a user in careers

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, jobs

In Careers: Will it be possible for me to view other CV's as somebody that looks for a job? How would you then filter out employees I should not see as I currently work with them? Overlapping current employers?

If so, how would you prevent my boss looking at my CV? He'ld just have to ommit his current employer.

Comment: I hope noone will be able to see CV apart from paid up employers, alless I send them a link to my CV  (like photos on facebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand:

Anyone can view a public CV and only paying employers can view a private CV. It is up to you if you want to publish your CV as private or public. In a way, you can see other public CV's but they won't be searchable or able to be browsed because that would defeat the purpose of the Careers business model.

Comment: not being able to browse other people's CVs on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ makes this service much less useful and attractive to me.  I'd like to use it to know what other developers, who share my interests, are doing.   And I'd like to find people to model myself.  Without browsing I don't know how to use careers for this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to browse other user's CVs on the public web, **if they have opted to publish their CV**. You'd have to know the CV URL that user has chosen, or arrive there via a Google search if someone has linked to the URL on a public web site, somewhere. This is all controlled via the Publish CV tab, and is a completely free service.

The private view of the CV is *only* ever visible to you.

**If you have paid to file**, then your private CV view is available to any employers who discover you through searches.

Comment: And do potential employers see whether you are currently looking for work? What happens if your current employer comes across this?